# How "WaitForPageLoad()" function in Selenium WebDriver works internally?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

How does "WaitForPagetOLoad() " function of Selenium work? How does the method detects the page load completion?

Thanks,
Dinesh

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/6b4e6de722fcccd18619951543143999e9a30657/java/client/src/com/thoughtworks/selenium/webdriven/commands/WaitForPageToLoad.java

As we see from here it waits some time (pre-defined or user defined) until javascript will not return `complete` for `document['readyState'];`.

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState :

> Returns "loading" while the document is loading, "interactive" once it
>   is finished parsing but still loading sub-resources, and "complete"
>   once it has loaded.

Comment: Hi Stanjer, Thanks for the helpful links. Document ready state, does that mean, once all java script loading completed in the page?

Comment: Particularly yes. But in common it means that the HTML DOM of the page has been loaded fully.